# Implementing an Append Method for my IntList Class in Java

Tags: java

I'm working through some problems from Modern Programming Languages by Webber and I'm having difficulty implementing an append method for an IntList x where the method takes another IntList y and is appended behind x. Here's the code:

```
public class IntList {
  private ConsCell start;

  public IntList cons (int h) {
    return new IntList(new ConsCell(h, start));
  }

  public int length() {
    int len = 0;
    ConsCell cell = start;
    while (cell != null) {
      len++;
      cell = cell.getTail();
    }
    return len;
  }

  public IntList append(IntList y) {
    ConsCell x = start;
    while (x.getTail() != nil) {
      x = x.getTail;
    }
    x = y.start;
    return new IntList(x);
  }
}
```

Heres the class for the ConsCell

```
public class ConsCell {
  private int head;
  private ConsCell tail;

  public ConsCell(int h, ConsCell t) {
    head = h;
    tail = t;
  }

  public int getHead() {
    return head;
  }

  public ConsCell getTail() {
    return tail;
  }
}
```

So my thought process behind the append method is

1. Go down the list until you reach the end (in this case when start.getTail is null)
2. Once the end of the list is reached, add the new IntList to the end of x
3. return the new IntList containing x and y

Unfortunately the program didn't work out as intended and I was wondering if anyone can give me some insight?

Comment: Should it be `x.tail = y.start` in your append method? And no need to return a new `IntList`. Just return itself, i.e., `this` should be enough.

Comment: In addition to what @Alex said; you should return the `start` and not the `x` position since it is now somewhere midway....Added the combination as answer

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, that really cleared things up for me :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `append` method should be like this

```
public IntList append(IntList y) {
    ConsCell x = start;
    while (x.getTail() != null) {
        x = x.getTail();
    }
    x.setTail(y.getStart());
    return this;
}
```

I assumed that you need to add setter method to your classes, since they are private and requires setter to access them. And it is a good habit to have setter and getter for variables.

And since you have directly changed the `ConsCell` instances in your `append` method, it would be no difference in returning itself or returning a new `IntList`. Modifying in both `IntList` will effectively modify the other one, since they are pointing to the same list of `ConsCell` instances.

If you really need a new `IntList` which is independent to the old one, you need to copy each element in `IntList` to a new `ConsCell`.

Comment: Thanks, I do need to great a new IntList so I'll try your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 public IntList append(IntList y) {
     ConsCell x = start;
     while (x.getTail() != null) {
         x = x.getTail();
     }
     x.tail = y.start;
     return new IntList(start);
 }
```